# Switching Remote Urls from HTTPS to SSH

Tags: github

I tried to switch from a HTTPS to SSH repo using git. Below are the first commands I used.

[image]

Then, when I tried to add a branch to the staging area, I got the following messages:

[image]

I am not able to push anything or add any commits to git from my command line either. I get an error saying "could not read remote repository". Could someone please help me? What should I do now? I am new to git and I don't want to dig myself in a deeper hole!

Answer (score 1):

Check for a `.git/` subfolder in:

- your current working directory (where you switch to SSH)
- your parent folders

If you see one in any *parent* folder, that would make your current working directory a nested Git repository.

Ideally, there should not be any parent Git repository above your own: see if you can remove those parent `.git` folders (or move them elsewhere).

Comment: So the parent folder would be the https repo in this case? And that I should delete?

Comment: @MichaelHorvilleur No, not an URL. A parent folder (`cd ..`, `cd ../..`, ....). I am talking about local path here.